# It's mentioned in Hadith that Dua is accepted on Wednesday between asar and maghrib

Tags: hadith

Reference of this Hadith is (الادب المفرد 704)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please check [ask].